# Is angirasa kalpa available?

Tags: scripture, resource

Is this book available anywhere for purchase or is there is an online digitial version?

Comment: I think, it is a part of Atharvaveda. Are you looking for same?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani its famous in orissa region. Some museum has its manuscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an online version of it, but it is available in print form, from the Odisha State Museum website.  [Here](http://odishamuseum.nic.in/?q=node/824) is one part of it and [here](http://odishamuseum.nic.in/?q=node/1015) I see another part of it.  They're scans of a palm leaf manuscript written in Oriya script.

It's also worth noting that this manuscript may not be the original Angirasa Kalpa of the Atharvana Veda; see [here](https://gairikshita.wordpress.com/2014/06/01/angirasa-kalpa-of-orissan-atharvavedins/).

Comment: When later upanishad can be.called as shruti then why not later kalpa.sutra. its blog owners.opinion and needs to be verified

Comment: @RakeshJoshi If a putative Upanishad is a later addition, it's most certainly not Shruti.  If someone is calling a particular Upanishad as Shruti, then they are making a claim that it's one of the original Upanishads.

Comment: you people.have repeatedly quoted so called sanyasa.upanishad and muktika canon

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I don't know what "you people" means, but I certainly don't consider either the Sanyasa Upanishads or the Muktika Upanishad to be authentic.  in any case, page 63 of [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=B1_WAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA63&img=1&pgis=1&dq=angirasa+kalpa+lost&sig=ACfU3U39Ox61G0-R64EmWLOFrJBfvinfOQ&edge=0) also says the original Angirasa Kalpa is lost.